# How to summarize row and column data?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Consider the following data:

[image: Sample Data]

First column has a lot of repeat numbers (category codes). The data comes to me in this general format but with many more rows and columns. The number of rows varies but there's usually 40 or so columns. I only need columns `1`, `2` and `6`. There will be an entry in column `4` ONLY or column `5` ONLY, never both, never neither. All I need is the column heading.

Thus, I want to reconfigure the data and display it on `Sheet 2` so that it looks like the following:

[image: Sample Output]

I don't want to use a macro or VBA as the company security settings can be troublesome. Is there a one-line command I could enter in Cell A1 that would produce the output I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data table is named `Table7`:
 (*Using a Table structure means the references will auto-adjust as you add/remove rows from the data table*)

[image]

You can enter the following formula in some single cell, and the results will `SPILL` to give your desired output:

```
=HSTACK(
    CHOOSECOLS(
        Table7,
        1,
        2,
        6
    ),
    BYROW(
        Table7[Fruit],
        LAMBDA(arr,
            IF(
                arr = "",
                "Vegetable",
                "Fruit"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

- `CHOOSECOLS` returns the desired columns for the output
- The `BYROW` function returns another column containing the item type depending on whether the `Fruit` cell is empty or not
- `HSTACK` combines the two into a single data table output

***Edit:***
*For a formula which will auto-adjust for multiple intervening columns to be adjusted, try the formula below*
*The formula will retain columns `1,2 and the last column` and will return the headers for columns `4-penultimate column`

```
=LET(
    firstCol, 4,
    numCols, COLUMNS(Table7) - 4,
    cols, SEQUENCE(, numCols, firstCol),
    hdrs, INDEX(Table7[#Headers], , cols),
    HSTACK(
        CHOOSECOLS(Table7, 1, 2, COLUMNS(Table7)),
        BYROW(
            LEN(CHOOSECOLS(Table7, cols)) > 0,
            LAMBDA(arr, XLOOKUP(TRUE, arr, hdrs))
        )
    )
)
```

Again, you may need to change the structured references to regular cell references.

- `LEN(CHOOSECOLS(Table7, cols)) > 0` returns a 2D array of `TRUE/FALSE` depending on if there is content in the cell.
- `BYROW` will match the `TRUE` entry to the corresponding Column Header/Name

Comment: Unfortunately the initial data is an export from software so it's not organized in a table (lots of Total rows, subheadings, etc). Yes, I could manipulate the data first but the goal is to have Excel read the raw export and create an organized data array from it.

I will test your code above. It might get me part of the way there!

Comment: @ZoltanZslabo You can replace the structured references with ordinary cell addresses. However, depending on what your real export looks like, it may be easier to manipulate in power query.

Comment: I think we're close. Instead of 2 columns D and E, there's actually closer to 40! However, the Total in Column F resides in 1 of those 40 columns. Your IF statement won't work.

Instead, I need to find the value in Column F somewhere in the 40 previous columns, then return the column header. Stripping out HSTACK and COLUMNS for now, here's where I'm stuck:

BYROW(F2:F6,
       LAMBDA(ARR,
              INDEX($D$1:$E$1,,
                   MATCH(ARR, D{row#]:E{row#])

I'm not sure how to tell MATCH to look at D2:E2, then D3:E3, etc?

Comment: @ZoltanZslabo See my edit for a formula solution given `n` number of columns

Comment: The revised code is amazing! It will take me an hour to understand it but it popped out exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adapt the following:

1. Filter the table and selecting only some rows by using either `CHOOSECOLS` or `FILTER` functions.

```
=CHOOSECOLS(A2:F6,{1,2,6})
```

OR

```
=FILTER(FILTER(A2:F6,A2:A6<>""),{1,1,0,0,0,1})
```

[image]

[image]

2. Find the index of the columns that matches the first two columns. Then, check if the fruit value is not empty. If that is the case, write "Fruit". If not, write "Vegetable".

```
=IF(INDEX($D$2:$D$6,MATCH(A10&B10,($A$2:$A$6)&($B$2:$B$6),0))<>"",$D$1,$E$1)
```

Drag the formula down to fill the other rows.

[image]

Comment: What I have is something similar to your solution but I was hoping to merge the two functions into a single function generating the 4 column output. This is the Plan B solution but I'm wracking my brain for a more elegant Plan A function.